# date difference produces wrong output in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, datediff

I have a table called employee  (see image):

[Example of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8kLf.png)

My trying to get their actual age by subtracting the current date from their dob using this code:

```
select datediff(CURDATE(), str_to_date(employee.dob,'%m/%d/%Y')) as age
FROM employee;
```

The output is as follows:

```
18357
273
```

My expected output should be :

```
29 
20
```

Note that: that dob is stored as a string in the table.

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample, your actual result and your expected  result

Comment: The DATEDIFF() function returns the number of days between two date values. What do you expect?

Comment: Store dates using a date data type

Comment: It did. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this to get the age in years:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), str_to_date(dob,'%m/%d/%Y'))), "%Y")+0 AS age 
FROM employee;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e500f9/2)